# Can you export a created python conda environment for others to activate on their machines?

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, environment-variables, conda

I do the following:

```
conda create -n myenv -c conda-forge jupyter xarray cmocean numpy matplotlib netCDF4 cartopy pandas

conda activate myenv

jupyter notebook
```

Is there a way that I can export this environment to another computer to be activated by another user?

I want other users to run my jupyter notebook script without having to install python packages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#sharing-an-environment.

1. Activate the environment to export: `conda activate myenv`
2. Export your active environment to a new file: `conda env export > environment.yml`
3. Email or copy the exported `environment.yml` file to the other person.

To create environment from `.yml` file: `conda env create -f environment.yml`
The first line of the yml file sets the new environment's name.

Comment: I tried this but get the following: `CondaValueError: prefix already exists: /Users/directory/environment`

Comment: In the first line of the created `environment.yml` file there is name of the environment to be created. You can 1) remove existing environment having that name, or 2) change the name in the file to different name.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can:

```
conda activate ENV
conda env export | grep -v "^prefix: " > environment.yml
```

The grep command removes your prefix. That yml file can be used by others as

```
 conda env create -f environment.yml
 conda activate ENV
```

Comment: I tried this but get the following: `CondaValueError: prefix already exists: /Users/directory/environment`

Comment: That is because you already have an environment with that name. Check `conda env list` and open yml file and see what name is there:  you can do `conda env remove -n ENV` before creating ENV from yml

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the complete folder of the environment. It can be found easily, where your python is installed.

Comment: How would someone else use this environment folder?